# Call a service only if there was no input for n milliseconds

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wondering whether there is a possibility using rxjs to achieve the following instruction programmatically with TypeScript:

**Call a service. But only when the last input in a textfield occurred n milliseconds or longer ago.**

e.g.

12:30.450 > 'K' was entered.

12:30.500 > 'E' was entered. gap is 50 ms. No action to be taken.

12:30.550 > 'Y' was entered. gap is 50 ms. No action to be taken.

12:31.050 > no input for the last 500 ms. CALL THE SERVICE.

I thought about using this construct:

```
return Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
    return this.compare().map(duplication => {
        return (duplication === true) ? { duplicateName: true } : null;
    });
});
```

But it provides only a delay. It won't ignore the call totally considering the given minimum gap time.

Has anybody an idea about how to tie up loose ends in this case?

Comment: Would the person who down voted this post be so kind and explain his/her decision? What is unclear about my question? Where didn't I provide enough information about what I intend to do and what I've tried on my own so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use DebounceTime see https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html

You can use the debounceTime filter to give yourself a gap of time to allow for more changes before triggering the observable to fire the next value.